# MVC4 OpenID Provider Action is not invoked as per URI in XRDS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, dotnetopenauth, xrds

I am trying to develop an OpenID Provider for Single Sign On capability in my company. I have little experience with either MVC 4 or the `DotNetOpenAuth` library.

I am trying to build the provider based on the examples downloaded from http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/site.

My provider is not invoked by the relying party but it does not invoke the URI mentioned in the Xdrs. The URI is being formed as

> `http://localhost:54589/OpenId/provider`

but the action for this url (the Provider action) is not being invoked. If I access this URL directly from the browser then it shows the view in the browser.

Below is the Xrds

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xrds:XRDS
    xmlns:xrds="xri://$xrds"
    xmlns:openid="http://openid.net/xmlns/1.0"
    xmlns="xri://$xrd*($v*2.0)">
    <XRD>
        <Service priority="10">
            <Type>http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server</Type>
            <Type>http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1</Type>
            <Type>http://axschema.org/contact/email</Type>
            <URI>http://localhost:54589/OpenId/Provider</URI>
        </Service>
    </XRD>
    </xrds:XRDS>
```

I am not sure whether this is an MVC problem OR I am not using `DotNetOpenAuth` correctly.

**Update**
On Debugging I found that my MVC razor Xrds.cshtml is being called but the relying party does not redirect to the URI exist in Xrds.  I also made sure that I am setting the Request.ContentType as application/Xrds+xml. Below is my code

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("application/xrds+xml"))
            {
                ViewData["OPIdentifier"] = true;
                return RedirectToAction("Xrds");
            }
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Xrds()
        {
            ViewData["OPIdentifier"] = true;
            Response.ContentType = "application/xrds+xml";
            return View("Xrds");
        }
```

When I see the request and response in Fiddler, it come back with result 200 where it should be 302.

### Does this mean that the xrds is not going back to relying party in proper format?

Here the fiddler trace

```
GET http://localhost:4856/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fMembersOnly%2fDefault.aspx HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Referer: http://localhost:4856/
Accept-Language: en-GB
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost:4856
Connection: Keep-Alive


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcbWFoZXNoLmNoYXVkaGFyaVxEb3dubG9hZHNcRG90TmV0T3BlbkF1dGgtNC4yLjIuMTMwNTVcRG90TmV0T3BlbkF1dGgtNC4yLjIuMTMwNTVcU2FtcGxlc1xPcGVuSWRSZWx5aW5nUGFydHlXZWJGb3Jtc1xsb2dpbi5hc3B4?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 11 Mar 2013 08:59:07 GMT
Content-Length: 9430



------------------------------------------------------------------

POST http://localhost:4856/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fMembersOnly%2fDefault.aspx HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Referer: http://localhost:4856/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fMembersOnly%2fDefault.aspx
Accept-Language: en-GB
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost:4856
Content-Length: 964
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcbWFoZXNoLmNoYXVkaGFyaVxEb3dubG9hZHNcRG90TmV0T3BlbkF1dGgtNC4yLjIuMTMwNTVcRG90TmV0T3BlbkF1dGgtNC4yLjIuMTMwNTVcU2FtcGxlc1xPcGVuSWRSZWx5aW5nUGFydHlXZWJGb3Jtc1xsb2dpbi5hc3B4?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 11 Mar 2013 08:59:14 GMT
Content-Length: 10382
```

Comment: Can you please add the fiddler trace for the request as well? 
And which controller did the two action methods you included come from?

Comment: Hello Andrew, The two methods are from the HomeController. Just that I redirect to action instead of returning the Xrds view directly. Even if I do that it makes no difference. I have updated the original question with the fiddler trace.